# Tap to scroll to top issue on position:fixed

Tags: html, ios, css, css-position

I made this example: a menu that has position:fixed, and a lot of list items. If you scroll down to the last item, and then tap the Safari menubar to scroll to top, that doesn't work.

http://mateitudor.com/learn/fixed/

Can anyone tell me why? Thank you.

Comment: What has scrolling to the top to do with `position: fixed`? When I click on the last list item I do get to the top because the page reloads (could also be solved with JavaScript).

Comment: Please read what I wrote again. This is not what I asked. Tapping on the Safari menubar twice won't scroll up if the container of that has overflow information has position:fixed.

Comment: Is it an iOS limitation, that position:fixed containers don't have tap-to-top functionality?